# How/where to use os.path.sep?

Tags: python, os.path

`os.path.sep` is the character used by the operating system to separate pathname components.

But when `os.path.sep` is used in `os.path.join()`, why does it truncate the path?

Example:

Instead of `'home/python'`, `os.path.join` returns `'/python'`:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('home', os.path.sep, 'python')
'/python'
```

I know that [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) inserts the directory separator implicitly.

Where is `os.path.sep` useful? Why does it truncate the path?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where os.path.sep is usefull?

I suspect that it exists mainly because a variable like this is required in the module anyway (to avoid hardcoding), and if it's there, it might as well be documented. Its documentation says that it is ["occasionally useful"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep).

> Why it truncates the path?

From the [docs for `os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

and `/` is an absolute path on *nix systems.

Answer (score 0):

Drop `os.path.sep` from the `os.path.join()` call. [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) uses `os.path.sep` internally.

On your system, `os.path.sep == '/'` that is interpreted as a root directory (absolute path) and therefore `os.path.join('home', '/', 'python')` is equivalent to `os.path.join('/', 'python') == '/python'`. [From the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join):

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown
>   away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

Answer (score 0):

As correctly given in the docstring of `os.path.join` -

> Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed. **If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components will be discarded.**

Same is given in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) as well -

> **os.path.join(path, *paths)**
>
> Join one or more path components intelligently. The return value is the concatenation of path and any members of *paths with exactly one directory separator (os.sep) following each non-empty part except the last, meaning that the result will only end in a separator if the last part is empty. **If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.**

When you give `os.path.sep` alone, it is considered as an absolute path to the root directory - `/` .

Please note , this is for unix/linux based os.path , which internally is `posixpath` . Though the same behavior is seen in windows `os.path.join()` .

Example -

```
>>> import os.path
>>> os.path.join.__doc__
"Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.\n    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components\n    will be discarded."
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the snippet of code that is run if you are on a `POSIX` machine:

**[posixpath.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/posixpath.py#L67)**

```
# Join pathnames.
# Ignore the previous parts if a part is absolute.
# Insert a '/' unless the first part is empty or already ends in '/'.

def join(a, *p):
    """Join two or more pathname components, inserting '/' as needed.
    If any component is an absolute path, all previous path components
    will be discarded.  An empty last part will result in a path that
    ends with a separator."""
    sep = _get_sep(a)
    path = a
    try:
        if not p:
            path[:0] + sep  #23780: Ensure compatible data type even if p is null.
        for b in p:
            if b.startswith(sep):
                path = b
            elif not path or path.endswith(sep):
                path += b
            else:
                path += sep + b
    except (TypeError, AttributeError, BytesWarning):
        genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
        raise
    return path
```

Specifically, the lines:

```
        if b.startswith(sep):
            path = b
```

And, since `os.path.sep` definitely starts with this character, whenever we encounter it we throw out the portion of the variable `path` that has already been constructed and start over with the next element in `p`.

Answer (score 0):

> But when os.path.sep is used in os.path.join() , why it truncates the path?

Quoting directly from the documentation of [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

> If a component is an absolute path, all previous components are thrown away and joining continues from the absolute path component.

So when you do:

```
os.path.join('home', os.path.sep, 'python')
```

`os.path.sep` returns `'/'` which is an absolute path, and so `'home'` is thrown away and you get only `'/python'` as the output.

This can is also clear from the example:

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.join('home','/python','kivy')
'/python/kivy'
```

> Where os.path.sep is usefull?

`os.path.sep` or `os.sep` returns the character used by the operating system to separate pathname components.
But again quoting from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.sep):

> Note that knowing this is not sufficient to be able to parse or concatenate pathnames — use os.path.split() and os.path.join() — but it is occasionally useful.